# Запятая в словосочетании "всё что у меня есть"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно — "ты всё, что у меня есть" или "ты всё что у меня есть"?

Answer (score 3):

**Ты всё, что у меня есть.**

Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным местоименно-определительным, запятая ставится.

Сравнить: **Бери что есть.**

Перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе **неразложимых сочетаний** запятая не ставится: **бери что дают** и др.

[**§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)